# My Firebase Realtime Database displays a blank empty view and doesn't even shows the name of my root directory

Tags: android, firebase, mobile, browser

Please can someone tell me why my Firebase Realtime Database root directory isn't showing any data? I'm using my mobile browser to view it. Or the reason why I'm facing this problem is because I'm viewing it with my mobile device?

**UPDATE**

To me i think it's a bug on their website or something because i only experience such issue when i perform too many operations on that same webpage due to manually updating records in the database and navigating backwards to see other previous data, and when the Realtime Database stops displaying my data, i give it few hours later in that same day and everything comes back to normal.

Comment: Definitely not related with you viewing Firebase from mobile, can you post a pic what exactly is displaying when you visit your database?

Comment: @GiorgosS. i tried adding a pic but Stack Overflow declined it because of my reputation. it's < 10. I'm new

Comment: If you try to view your database root from your pc does it display correctly?

Comment: @GiorgosS. okay my second problem now is i don't have a PC, so that's why I'm asking if anyone knows, if the problem is coming from my phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading Chrome browser to your phone and check again. If you still see this problem tap on the three dots on the upper right corner of chrome and select "request desktop site"

That should do it.

Comment: but I've already done those and still it doesn't work, sometimes it shows the database directory as expected & sometimes it doesn't (like now it doesn't) i thought the problem was from them. I'll try and test it with a PC to know if it works. thanks for the support

Comment: thanks!!!!! i​ tried it again and it worked!!! i selected the "Request Desktop Site". but i did this before and there was no difference, but now it has made a difference. thanks!!